Bicyclic isomers of C6H10
How many bicyclic isomers (including spiro compounds), of C6H10 are there? This narrows down the problem, excluding isomers without double or triple bonds. I've spent a lot of time on it and only got 17.

Could you share your thoughts?

(1) Why do you need this number? (2) Do you only want structural isomers, or geometrical isomers as well?

Yes, I only need the structural isomers

A quick search on MOLGEN (formula: C6H10, cycles: 2) yields 17 structures only.
